# Mongoose save same model to mutiple collections dynamically

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

Is it possible to save the mongoose injected model to multiple collections? (nestjs inection)

I'm looking for something like

```
injectedMode.collection('collectionA').save(data);
injectedMode.collection('collectionB').save(data);
```

Sometimes I need to save the model to one collection, and sometimes to another.
Please remember that the model is injected, and in my case, I want to have a collection per customer. so the same model needs to **dynamically** be saved to a specific collection

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NestJS allows you to acccess the native [Mongoose Connection](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#connection) which in turn provides access to the connection's `db`-object, so you could create the following service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DynamicMongoDbService {
  constructor (@InjectConnection() private connection: Connection) {
  }

  async insert(collectionName: string, data: any) {
    return this.connection.db.collection(collectionName).insert(data);
  }
}
```

and later use this service accordingly:

```
this.dynamicMongoDbService.insert('collectionA', data);
this.dynamicMongoDbService.insert('collectionB', data);
```

---

Edit:

If the models are known at compile time, you could also create a service which injects all the required models and stores them in a map. Then, when using the service, you dynamically decide which model to choose from and delegate to it:

```
@Injectable()
export class DynamicMongoDbService {

  private modelMap: Record<string, Model<any>>;

  constructor (
    @InjectModel(Cat.name) catModel: Model<Cat>,
    @InjectModel(Dog.name) dogModel: Model<Dog>) {
    this.modelMap = {
      [Cat.name]: catModel,
      [Dog.name]: dogModel
    };
  }

  async insertDynamically<M, T> (modelType: typeof M, data: T) {
    const model = this.modelMap[modelType.name];
    return model.save(data);
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
this.dynamicMongoDbService.insert(Cat, data);
this.dynamicMongoDbService.insert(Dog, data);
```

Comment: By doing this, do I lose the ability to inject the model, and all the benefit of strong type capabilities and API, no? can I still use the model?. and what about queries? thank you!

Comment: That's true, maybe there's another way - I'll think about it :)

Comment: Edited the answer, what do you thing of this idea?

Comment: It is nice, but the problem is that I need a collection per customer (its kind of isolated cloud per customer). so ill probably will have to: `customerA: Model<Data>` - its not known at compile time... thanks for trying to help.